# Searching for the original definition of online algorithms

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, online-algorithms

I'm currently searching for the original formal definition of online algorithms. The earliest mentions of online algorithms that I found are from the mid 80s. But none of these papers seem to be the one that was the original reference.

Note: English is my second language.

Comment: Get a copy of [Borodin and El-Yaniv's text](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=7726049700429222225&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22) on online algorithms.  The [first page of their preface](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=v3faI8pER6IC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&ots=A7x3GKSO3T&sig=lZG0cIhY16KF8K5dHvU_NzQGwxo#v=onepage&q&f=false) discusses the history.  They mention Graham's analysis of the online greedy algorithm for scheduling jobs on identical processors, and the analysis of self-adjusting data structures (e.g. list management)

Comment: Section 3(Historical Background) of https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0029562 contains some historical remarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks.

With Garmow's comment I was able to find the first two references which also called on-line algorithms as on-line:

[Johnson, David S. "Fast algorithms for bin packing." Journal of Computer and System Sciences 8.3 (1974): 272-314.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000074800267)

and

[Johnson, David S. Near-optimal bin packing algorithms. Diss. Massachusetts Institute of Technology, 1973.](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/57819/17595570-MIT.pdf?sequence=2)